# NULL pointer exception while using JavaMailSender in Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use the java mail API in my JSF project,but it keeps throwing a null pointer exception at the line `mailSender.createMimeMessage()`.I am using method below within a Managed Bean in JSF.

```
public void sendMail(Context ctx, String[] bcc, String address,
        String subject, String page) {

    try {

        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setFrom("from@xyz.com");
        message.setBcc(bcc);
        message.setTo(address);
        final String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(page, ctx);

        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Send email
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
}
```

Again, the line `mailSender.createMimeMessage` throws a null pointer exception.

What could I be missing? Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.purple.mailer.MailerTemplateBean.sendMail(MailerTemplateBean.java:165)
at com.purple.mailer.MailerTemplateBean.sendMail(MailerTemplateBean.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:792)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1257)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:95)
at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.purple.util.URLFilter.doFilter(URLFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you please show us how is your mailSender variable being initialized/injected?

Comment: @cghislai indeed. There is probably something wrong with the injection from the mailSender since mailSender is the only thing that CAN be null at that line.

Comment: @cghislai I tried injecting using the "@Autowired JavaMailSender mailSender" and I even tried specifying it in a different class and injecting it within the managed bean as follows "@ManagedProperty(value="#{EmailService}") IEmailService emailService;" and accessing sendMail from this but it dint help resolving the null pointer exception. I am new to Jsf concepts so I would be more than glad if you can help me out.Thank you.

Comment: I use a mail service as a  `@Stateless @ManagedBean`, with an injected `@Resource(name = '/mail/your-jndi-path') javax.mail.Session session`. Then I can access it using simple `@EJB` injection.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, actually there was an issue in the config file,its resolved now.